# Add child css class to parent css class for drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, primefaces

I am trying to add a child css class to a parent css class for a drop down menu. When the user clicks on the parent css class called .linkBox it brings up a drop down list. The child css class that needs to appear is a css generated arrow. I have the arrow centered, but everything I've tried to get the arrow to appear hasn't worked. I have to use both as css classes, they cannot be IDs. The second part of this is that the arrow will only effect the first and third box in the header. The other issue is that the project calls for the use of PrimeFaces and I think that might be part of what is throwing me off. This is what I have so far-

```
 $('.linkBox').hover (function () {
       $(this).parent('.linkBox').children('p').addClass("ddArrow");
  },function () {
    $(this).parent('.linkBox').children('p').removeClass("ddArrow");
  }
);
```

The PrimeFaces code is-

```
 <p:panel id="profileDropDown" styleClass="linkBox profileBox">
```

Help I've been stuck on this for days!
Thank you!!!!

Comment: In the hover handler `this` refers to the `linkBox` element... so `$(this).find('p').addClass("ddArrow")` should do... also it will be great if you can share the generated html...

Comment: Why use JavaScript? CSS can do it!  `.linkBox:hover p { color: red; }`

Comment: can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ without the html and css we won't be able to help much

Comment: sure I will put it together real quick

Comment: Here it is on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xc6sD/

Comment: instead of the server template can you share the generated html... from the browser source

Comment: Here is the generated HTML - http://jsfiddle.net/xc6sD/1/

Comment: @user2285352, There is no `<p>` under the linkBox div. thus hover is not working

Comment: Add a p element then it should be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hmx9y/1/

Comment: without the hover handler http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hmx9y/2/

Comment: Is it possible to change the hover to a click? I tried using the .click and .on and the arrow disappears